# Why not always use a higher millicandela (MCD) rated LED?

Tags: led, current

Take this [comparison of two SMD LEDs](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/compare?s=N4IgzCBcDa4BwDY4CYCcIA0JlgKwOWQEYQBdLAFihAHoBTAOxoAcAnAewBMBXAYwBcAzjQBmASwA2-OqxoS6nALRiGnMbwCG-MewaK1g3qzrSaRAAy4A-IIC8AOQoBJAOYArAMIAhXsxcAjADF2ABEAcQBVLwBbLxCAQXsXAC0AdwBpAE0vdgBFLwB2dPj-ACV4sOyAeXiAKRcvZIovTniG1J88rwkANRda1IBRQXjOFwAJAFlc%2BIANVIAZAGt4gviACxDapwR-AAUxdKXinrcvdZ74kPWvaf8Q-jACjwAPLwB1WtKJAE9A7niggi6wkGniXiWzB6P24Em45nWnDoLiWdD2Xi0YQKuUEAEcxJl7IJWMhAlUAMpVd5iArcACkyC8zAKdBeDAQOhWIAAvkA) as an example. They are basically the same LED, except one has a 12mcd rating and the other a 65mcd rating. By adjusting the resistor in series, couldn't the later consume less current whilst maintaining the same brightness level of the former?

If selecting between these two LEDs, why would I ever use the lower millicandela rated LED? Isn't less current always better?

Comment: Isn't less cost always better? One costs a LOT more.

Comment: Well, the lower brightness one is cheaper...

Comment: The lower brightness one also has a somewhat better temperature range.

Comment: Recently I repaired some device with a blue LED. When the cover was removed that LED was so bright that it did hurt the eye, and I covered it with the finger, just to be able to look at the circuit board. Half the brightness would still have been enough!

Comment: I'm sure that the price difference is also negligible, as the prices vary a lot across distributors, and it's possible to find a good deal on almost any component at big enough quantities.

Comment: @U.Windl if it hurts the eye, 1/100 of the brightness is probably good for an indicator.

Comment: So just to clarify, for my particular project the cost is the least important thing - I want to draw as little current as possible.

Comment: @scottc11 -- To draw as little current as possible, switch over to the LED's designed for Lighting applications, and look for maximum Lumens per Watt figure, then underpower them. Lime green is the most efficient.  [LUXEON 3535L LED Lighting Color series Lime green, 184 Lumens/Watt @ 100mA => 56 lm, 3.05V Vf, SMD 1414 or 3535 Metric, $1.70](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/lumileds/L135-L567003500000/5001155)

Comment: @scottc11 -- Or you can use [**this DigiKey search.**](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/led-lighting-color/125?s=N4IgjCBcoMwOxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIMArGGJQBwiEwBslADAEwyMgAsMbZjA4gAuoQAOAFyggAylIBOASwB2AcxABfQswCciECkgYcBYmT5s9MGz17XeHNmMkzI8pWs07wMXryGxqZ4hCSQ5DQ2tDw0dBxwzLG0YBwGhGCCHELJbIlJGWxsdPGxbGBwYIGFeWk8ekIclDx0lMIIhK10dp3M1i6denCJ9XkwDIR6YKwdIFN6C-XU%2BkvtS3AcEOIg0rIKKhrahAC0ItBGUEoArubh5M2iWr5J58oAJrJg-tU77p4HmkIUgAnhJcLI3tgUE8gA)

Comment: @scottc11 -- Conceivably, you could also use a high Lumen per Watt white LED, with or without colored plastic filter. Using plastic filter with or without masking might give you a very unique look. And efficient white LED's are cheap. (For fun, you can extract them super-cheap from dollar store LED lights).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming cost and availability aren't a concern, or other more subtle properties -- sure.

Note the viewing angles are the same, so the visual intensity should indeed be somewhat better for the 65mcd part.  You will see quite high mcd values for narrow angle LEDs, which isn't anomalous, it's simply the same total amount of light focused to a narrower cone.

The difference isn't huge, despite 65 being over five times larger than 12.  The eye has a logarithmic response, and it will be perceived as more like double the brightness.

Note also, there is a third option.  The two options are traditional GaP (gallium phosphide) green, which has quite poor efficacy: despite the eye's strong sensitivity to green, the mcd/mA is worse than red or yellow (GaAlAsP alloy) types.  However, modern GaInN (gallium indium nitride) technology offers a green, which is slightly bluer (versus the slightly yellowish hue of GaP), and despite the higher Vf (3V), has fantastically higher efficacy.

As with the spate of blindingly poorly used blue LEDs in the mid 2000s, when they became widely available -- GaInN green are very intense, and can be used as indicators at low currents say 1mA or even less.

Comment: Since they replaced the colored light bulbs with LEDs in traffic lights here, I realized how "ugly" the light from those green LEDs is: It hurts the eye!

Comment: @U.Windl Hopefully you're not spending too much time staring at green lights in traffic - there's other people behind you that have places to be...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I recognize the humor in you comment, but you are aware that the human eye is most sensitive to shades of green, and any narrow spectrum colored light source is against the evolutional tuning of the eye's receptors. Narrow-band high intensity may be perceived as low intensity while the receptor in the eye might be overloaded already. I agree that this leads away from the original question.

Answer (score 3):

The LEDs are not basically same, but completely different.

For you it might not matter if you only look at the brightness versus current.

For other purposes, they might be incompatible. They have different size, different peak wavelength, different peak power and current handling, different forward voltage curve, and price.

Comment: The size is within 0603 tolerances with 0.1 mm height difference, the peak wavelength difference is less than 10 nm with 30 nm spectral width, the current and forward voltage ratings differ by 0.2 V with +- 0.4V variance. The price difference is the only significant difference I see.

Comment: @jpa I know my applications aren't typical, but 10nm shift would be a big deal here even with a 30nm linewidth (we sometimes filter, but are often matching the peak to a material's response)

Comment: @jpa a 10nm spectral offset could be catastrophic for any photometer-like device. One of the two LEDs has no spectral binning options and as such, that model is disqualified for most light/transmission sensing applications.

Comment: @markus-nm That's even less reason to consider the 12 mcd variant (which is the one that lacks spectral binning). The question was why would someone want it.